# Docker Desktop for windows + WSL2 (ubuntu) ( on Win10 Home)

Tags: docker, wsl-2

I am able to run containers fine with this combination.
But I noticed - there is no /etc/docker directory on the linux side and when I do ps -eF  I get this. I was expecting dockerd and container processes as children of dockerd

```
rookie@MAIBENBEN-PC:/mnt/c/Users/rookie$ ps -eF
UID        PID  PPID  C    SZ   RSS PSR STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0   223   580   6 04:07 ?        00:00:00 /init
root        98     1  0   223    80   5 04:07 ?        00:00:00 /init
root        99    98  0   223    80   5 04:07 ?        00:00:00 /init
rookie     100    99  0 191067 43220  0 04:07 pts/0    00:00:00 docker serve --address unix:///home/rookie/.docker/run/d
root       101    98  0     0     0   1 04:07 ?        00:00:00 [init] <defunct>
root       103    98  0   223    80   7 04:07 ?        00:00:00 /init
root       104   103  0 384463 28888  0 04:07 pts/1    00:00:00 /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop/docker-desktop-proxy --distro-na
root       142     1  0   223    80   4 05:17 ?        00:00:00 /init
root       143   142  0   223    80   6 05:17 ?        00:00:00 /init
rookie     144   143  0  2509  5048   2 05:17 pts/2    00:00:00 -bash
rookie     221   144  0  2654  3264   7 05:21 pts/2    00:00:00 ps -eF
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Ubuntu session (and all WSL2 sessions) are set up as docker *clients*, but the actual docker daemon is running in a separate WSL session named "docker-desktop".

I generally recommend leaving this instance alone, as it is auto-configured and managed by Docker Desktop, but if you really want to take a look, run:

```
wsl -d docker-desktop
```

... from PowerShell, CMD, or Windows Start/Run.

Note that this instance is running BusyBox, so some commands will be different than you expect.  For instance, the `-F` argument is not valid for `ps`.

You'll see `dockerd` and the associated `containerd` processes here.

There's also a separate image, *docker-desktop-data*, but it is not bootable (there is no `init` in it).  If you want to see the filesystem, at least, you can `wsl --export` it and examine the tar file that is created.  I wrote up an [answer on Super User](https://superuser.com/q/1613589/1210833) with details a few months ago.

Comment: Right!. Too much magic. 
a) I wonder if there is a way to specify to docker desktop - "use this wsl distro (in this case ubuntu) as the server."
b) even if it needs to create it busy box distro, I wonder why it needs another wsl session as the client - why not just do it  on windows natively - I thought the client is just the CLI passing on commands to docker engine via rest API

Comment: To answer the "Why" - I'm guessing because Docker Desktop is a Windows app, it's best to have the "controlled environment" WSL2 instance where it knows it's dependencies are all met (and that it can update when it needs to without fear of modifying your working environment).  To answer (a) - I'm fairly sure this is possible. At the least, you can manually install Docker into any WSL2 instance that meets its dependencies.  I believe you can then point Docker Desktop to that instance through the Docker Engine settings.